# Not being able to go to specific page in woocommerce pagination

Tags: woocommerce

I have dropdown for number of products per page. It is working properly. but when I change number of products pagination gets affected.
Now what I need is I want the pagination to reset and start form page 1 whenever I change the number of products. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was up against the same thing and when the product number is changed I set the form action for the shop page url so that it returns to the starting page...seems to work alright.

```
<?php $action = get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );?>
    <form action="<?php echo $action;?>" method="POST" name="results" class="paging-form">
    <select name="woocommerce-sort-by-columns" id="woocommerce-sort-by-columns" class="sortby" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```